# Auto suggest choosing input matched selection in selenium python doesnt work

Tags: jquery, python, selenium

I have tried several ways to get autocomplete for selecting input value but not succeeded. It is selecting only first value in drop list. Please help to fix this.

```
first_field = Select(WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='bdy']/div[4]/ul/li"))))
#option_select = (browser.find_elements_by_xpath( "//*[@id='bdy']/div[4]ul/li"))

for elm in first_field:
    if(elm.text == (campus_name)):

      elm.click()

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located ((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='campus_result']")))
```

**I am giving input to id :autoCampusId and wants to select from Dropdown list names, which matches my input string.**

And select only matched string input in dropdown list.

[Click here to view the source code screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQg3J.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only when dropdown is a HTML native dropdown which defined by Select & Option Tag, you can use the `Select` class.

Your auto-suggest list is not native dropdown, it's a css simulated dropdown, so you should operate it as button or text field by finding it and clicking it.

**Option 1)** directly click on the wanted option

```
def select_campus(campus_name):

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#autoCampusId')
        .sendKeys(campus_name)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR , "div.ac_results li"))

    auto_suggest_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.ac_results li')

    found = false;

    print '@' + campus_name.upper() + '@'
    for item in auto_suggest_list:
        print '#' + item.text.upper() + '#'
        print 'location: ' + item.location
        if(item.text.strip().upper() == campus_name.strip().upper()):
            print 'find matched option'
            item.click()
            found = true
            break

    if found == false :
        print 'Can not find campus: ' + campus_name
```

**Option 2)** Use Down Key move to wanted option

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def select_campus(campus_name):

    input_ele = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#autoCampusId');
    input_ele.sendKeys(campus_name)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR , "div.ac_results li"))

    auto_suggest_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.ac_results li')

    for item in auto_suggest_list:

        if(item.text.strip().upper() != campus_name.strip().upper()):
            input_ele.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN)
        else:
            input_ele.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
            break
```

A tip: From your screenshot for HTML code, the `div.ac_results` is not visible (there is `display: none` in style attribute).  Selenium can't operate on invisible element also its descendants.

Comment: Given code didn't selecting from dropdown list it display only sendkey value

Comment: Please show your dropdown HTML and highlight or tell which option you want to choose. More detail what's input and what's output

Comment: Thanks for your reply. updated screenshot of output screen and source code. if you have any doubts please let me know

Comment: Tried with given code, it clicks first value in list but not matched value.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show the output of my code,  did you found anything when you debug my code?

Comment: Sure.  Inputted value is "SARASWATHI" and after search displayed matched name in 6th place in drop down list. it clicked first name  in drop down list.  i did not do debugging will debug code now and let you know

Comment: Can we try with Key.ARROWDOWN for selecting matched name?

Comment: Can you show the outout of `print item.text.upper()` in the loop

Comment: print item.text.upper()  shows output "SARASWATHI"  which is same as input value, but it wont effect in item.click() and it selects first value in dropdown list  "SARASWATHI SADAN"

Comment: Here is the Output :@SARASWATHI@
#SARASWATHI SADAN#
Can not find campus: SARASWATHI
#SARASWATHI G1 GIRLS CAMPUS#
Can not find campus: SARASWATHI
#SARASWATHI DHEERAJ GIRLS RES#
Can not find campus: SARASWATHI
#SARASWATHI SOUDHAM#
Can not find campus: SARASWATHI
#SARASWATHI BHAVAN#
Can not find campus: SARASWATHI
#SARASWATHI#
find matched option   (  but selected  SARASWATHI SADAN)

Comment: ok i will track location .. can we try with Key.Down or key.Arrowdown keys?

Comment: Can you please give index matched location. Because I have tried it also but it giving errors as keyboard cannot reached to tags i.e ac_even ac_over

Comment: output of item.location()  @SARASWATHI@
#SARASWATHI SADAN#
location: {'x': 229, 'y': 212}
Can not find campus: SARASWATHI
#SARASWATHI G1 GIRLS CAMPUS#
location: {'x': 229, 'y': 232}
Can not find campus: SARASWATHI
#SARASWATHI DHEERAJ GIRLS RES#
location: {'x': 229, 'y': 252}
Can not find campus: SARASWATHI
#SARASWATHI SOUDHAM#
location: {'x': 229, 'y': 272}
Can not find campus: SARASWATHI
#SARASWATHI BHAVAN#
location: {'x': 229, 'y': 292}
Can not find campus: SARASWATHI
#SARASWATHI#
location: {'x': 229, 'y': 312}
find matched option

Comment: if (item.text.strip().upper() == campus_name.strip().upper()):
            item.click()
            found = True
            break
        else:
            item.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
            time.sleep(20)
error occured as :  selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <li class="ac_even ac_over"> is not reachable by keyboard